# WPF PRISM - Display multiple pop-up view on the same time

Tags: wpf, navigation, prism, regions

My Shell Window contains a secondary pop-up region from the Stock Trader RI demo application

```
infBehaviors:RegionPopupBehaviors.CreatePopupRegionWithName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.SecondaryRegion}"
```

I am activating my views using the regionManager's RequestNavigate method:

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.SecondaryRegion, new Uri(FooView, UriKind.Relative));
```

Everything works fine if I work just with a single View. However in my case I want to have multiple Pop-up Windows at once - like having multiple pop-up regions at once. It seems that the problem lies in the activation/deactivation of the views inside the region.

How to "persuade" not to deactivate my previous view inside the region?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the solution is easier than I expected. Here is the solution in case if enybody needs it.

I just had to modify the RegionPopupBehaviours to use AllActiveregion instead of the original SingleActiveRegion and in the DialogActivation I had to remove the first call to the CloseContentDialog.

Hope that is helps.

Comment: I tried the same, but got an exception at the Region.Deactivate in ContentDialogClosed. If i comment that out too, if i close the popup it never comes up. I thought the solution is to create multiple regions each time by calling RegisterNewPopupRegion from the RegionPopupBehaviors. If your solution works that would be much simpler. Anything else you did other than the ones mentioned above?

Comment: did you mean you succeeded to show multiple popups at the same time? can you provide more code how did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue and I thought I would expand on @Sebastjan's post since it might help someone down the road.

Using the code from the Stock Trader RI demo, in the RegionPopupBehaviors class, the RegisterNewPopupRegion method should look like this:

```
public static void RegisterNewPopupRegion(DependencyObject owner, string regionName)
    {
        IRegionManager regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
        if (regionManager != null)
        {
            IRegion region = new AllActiveRegion(); //This was changed from SingleActiveRegion
            DialogActivationBehavior behavior;
            behavior = new WindowDialogActivationBehavior();
            behavior.HostControl = owner;

            region.Behaviors.Add(DialogActivationBehavior.BehaviorKey, behavior);
            regionManager.Regions.Add(regionName, region);
        }
    }
```

For anyone that doesn't have the code sample for the stock trader app, you can find it [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Prism-for-WPF-Reference-0f9aa651)